# can't get SSRS 2008 IIF statement with DatePart to work

Tags: reporting-services

I'm getting an error when I use the statement below.  I'm using an IIF statement to get the correct week number.  The week numbers are different for 2016 than other years so my old expression is returning one week number later than it should -- the old: `=DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!REQ_DATE.value)`.

what I have written but am getting an error and I cannot figure out what the problem is:

```
=IIF(=DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Fields!REQ_DATE.Value) =
“2016”,=DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!REQ_DATE.Value) –
1,=DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!REQ_DATE.Value))
```

basically, if the year of the field `REQ_DATE` is 2016, I want the `WeekOfYear` for `REQ_DATE - 1`; else just the `WeekOfYear`.

can anyone help me?  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `=` for every function you call in an expression, use the `=` only once at the beginning of the whole expression.

Try:

```
=IIF(DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Fields!REQ_DATE.Value) =
"2016",DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!REQ_DATE.Value) –
1,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!REQ_DATE.Value))
```

Comment: thanks -- but I tried that but now am getting this error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter "FalsePart" of 'Public Function IIF(Expression as Boolean, TruePart as object, FalsePart as object) as Object'   ?

Comment: well ok.  It had something to do with the " - 1" part.  I just retyped it and now it's working!  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @KimJones, nice! If my answer solved your issue you can select it as correct by right clicking the correct symbol in the left side.